# Shuffle an Array and Return a New One in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, shuffle

I want to know how to shuffle an array and return a NEW array. So far I have seen this solution in Stack Overflow:

[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

This solution works perfectly in returning the same array shuffled, but I don't really understand why. Can anyone explain this and help me revise it so that it returns a new array?

Thanks!

Comment: You want it to not modify your original array but just return a new one (a copy)?

Comment: You'll want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I know of to create a copy of an array is using:

```
var newArray = [].concat(originalArray);
```

You could perform that in the first line of most of the solutions on the linked answer and you would be getting a new array back with the original untouched. Here is a modified version of the top rated answer on the linked question:

```
function shuffle(originalArray) {
  var array = [].concat(originalArray);
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Comment: [Clone Arrays with JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array) suggests `var array = originalArray.slice(0);`.

Comment: @Ouroborus yes that is another way of cloning arrays. I don't think you should modify the `Array` prototype though, as he suggests. Also, `concat` appears to be significantly faster than `slice`: https://jsperf.com/test-slice-vs-concat/1

Comment: Actually, it's only significantly faster in Chrome, in Safari they are about equal and Firefox `slice` is significantly faster. Oh browsers... :P

Comment: Great thank you Rob! That seemed so simple, so I think I was just making it more complicated than it was. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe useful for you

```js
var original = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var copy = [].concat(original);
copy.sort(function(){
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 3rd party library, [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) is very good for this.

Just use [`_.shuffle()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#shuffle), to get new array.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const shuffle = (array) => {
  const mutatedArray = [...array];

  for (let i = mutatedArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [mutatedArray[i], mutatedArray[j]] = [mutatedArray[j], mutatedArray[i]];
  }

  return mutatedArray;
};
console.log(shuffle(["a", "b", "c", "d"]))
```

Powered by Fisher-Yates algorithm.